# Few line of codes are geting escaping at active admin custom page page_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

While working with `Active Admin`-> `Custom Page` -> `page_action`, I am facing difficulty in following code block pointed in the code. I was trying to test code reachablity by exception. I don't understand why won't I get exception if I place exception in position 2 in the code?

```
page_action :add_event, method: :post do
  blogit_posts=params["featured_post"]["blog_posts_attributes"].values.map { |s| 
    {
      :blogit_post_id=>s["blogit_post_id"],
      :id=> s["id"] ? s["id"] : s["i/nd"],
      :priority=>s["priority"],
      :_destroy=>s["_destroy"]
    } 
  }

  blogit_posts.each do |blog_hash|

      #raise "unknown" <-- 1. if i put here, I get exception for it

      if blog_hash[:id]
        b=BlogPost.find_by_id(blog_hash[:id].to_i)
      else if blog_hash[:blogit_post_id]
        b=BlogPost.find_by_blogit_post_id(blog_hash[:blogit_post_id].to_i)
      end

      #raise "unknown" <-- 2. if i put here, I **DO NOT** get exception for it

      if blog_hash[:_destroy] && blog_hash[:_destroy]=="1"   

        b.is_featured=false # <--- trying to fix this code block 

      else
        b.is_featured=true
      end
    b.priority =blog_hash[:priority].to_i
    b.save
  end
end
 redirect_to admin_featuredpost_path, notice: "Featurd post updated "
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were trying to format the code appropriately, you would’ve immediately found the error:

```
if blog_hash[:id]
    b=BlogPost.find_by_id(blog_hash[:id].to_i)
else 
    if blog_hash[:blogit_post_id]
      b=BlogPost.find_by_blogit_post_id(blog_hash[:blogit_post_id].to_i)
    end

    ???
```

That said, you have opened `if`, that is closed 15 lines below. One should either use `elsif` for spaghetti `if`s or properly close nesting `if`s.

Answer (score 1):

You probably are having trouble with this block:

```
if blog_hash[:id]
  b=BlogPost.find_by_id(blog_hash[:id].to_i)
else if blog_hash[:blogit_post_id]
  b=BlogPost.find_by_blogit_post_id(blog_hash[:blogit_post_id].to_i)
end
```

I believe what you meant was to write this:

```
if blog_hash[:id]
  b=BlogPost.find_by_id(blog_hash[:id].to_i)
elsif blog_hash[:blogit_post_id]
  b=BlogPost.find_by_blogit_post_id(blog_hash[:blogit_post_id].to_i)
end
```

please notice the `elsif`